# Error message - You need to specify full path to an executable file+mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC project- for changing the default browser I added a web form and by right-clicking, I changed the default browser, but now when I tried to run the MVC app it showing an error pop up."You need to specify the full path to an executable file"
Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: edit your question and supply more information.

Answer (score 16):

1. Right click on Project file ( .csproj) and select `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Web` tab.
3. Choose specific page radio button ( its The start external program causing the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same default browser trick that you did and ended up with the same error every time I tried to run the app.

I tried:

- Using 'Browse With...' and manually pointing to the exe of one of the browsers

No joy

- running devenv /resetsettings

No joy

- Installing [WoVS Default Browser Switcher](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921/) and switching between browsers

No Joy

- In the project properties changing to 'Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application' then changing back to 'Specific Page'

No more error!

As far as I know the last step is all that was needed but just in case a previous step had a side effect I thought I'd list them all.

Hope that fixes your problem, it's a truly awful error.